# What Architecture should i follow to upload video files on facebook and Youtube from my iso App

Tags: ios, file-upload, architecture

App feature: App in which user can share videos on youtube OR facebook.

what i want user start upload single OR multiple videos at time.

1. now what should the Architecture ?
2. am i allow to upload multiple videos at same time OR upload it one
   by one?
3. how to track if video on upload or there is an error during
   uploading.
       (upload that file again and move after uploading OR leave it for now
       and upload next)?
4. is status should show to user of only uploading file OR
       all files?

I am not asking any help regarding coding this Question is all about logic.
I create and simple architecture of that feature but i think it should be more optimise.

[image]

Comment: A question like this is better suite to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: And please rotate your image. It's tough turning my iMac on its side.